# Genesis Child Theme Modifying Comments display

Tags: comments, genesis-theme-framework

I'm using a theme which works with Genesis Framework. The theme is called pinsomo & I'm wondering how to "move" comments count div to the bottom of the post.

Here is the demo: [[link has expired]]

You see the comment icon next to the title. I want to move it to the heart icon.

Comment: Please post relevant code, otherwise, we have no way to provide answers.

Comment: The problem is that this is the first tiem I work with Genesis FW, or any FW, or any child theme. There are folders -> structure in `themes/genesis` and `themes/pinsomo`. I just need some suggestions where the SINGLE post layout is stored. Or something like this. Thanks!

Comment: But Geneisis is a commercial Theme, so we don't have access to the code to give you that information, or to know if it is Genesis-specific or WordPress-specific. It may or may not have anything to do with Genesis, but without seeing the code, we have no way to know.

Comment: Search your theme files for [`comments_number`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number). If you can find that-- if the theme(s) even use that function-- then post the surrounding code. That is the bit you need to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the genesis_post_info and genesis_post_meta filters in your child theme rather than modify the parent theme frameworks files which will be lost when you update Genesis.

Remove comments link from post info

```
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'remove_post_info_comments_link' );

function remove_post_info_comments_link($post_info) {

$post_info = '[post_date] by [post_author_posts_link] [post_edit]';
return $post_info;
}
```

Add comments link to post meta

```
add_filter( 'genesis_post_meta', 'add_comments_post_meta' );

function add_comments_post_meta($post_meta) {

$post_meta = '[post_categories] [post_tags] [post_comments]';
return $post_meta;
}
```

**Note:** This code only works with themes running HTML 5 markup.